# Weird SSL/TLS issue in Azure web app

Tags: azure, ssl, https, trust

I have 3 web apps in Azure. For illustration purposes let's just call them Service_A, Service_B, and Service_C.

Service_A calls Service_B, which in turn calls Service_C. Service_A also calls Service_C.

Service_A -> Service_C works fine.
Service_B -> Service_C works when Service_B is run on localhost and calls Service_C which is located in Azure), but *not* when Service_B is run in Azure.

Service_B uses the .NET HttpClient to make REST calls to Service_C via HTTPS.

Service_B fails with a HttpRequestException *("An error occurred while sending the request")* which has an inner exception of type WebException *("The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.")*.

Chrome reports the following about the certificate (which is Microsoft's Azure certificate):

`Protocol:          TLS 1.2
Key Exchange:       ECDHE_RSA
Key Exchange Group: P-256
Cipher:             AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1`

It says the cipher is obsolete. Mentioning it just in case, even though it doesn't seem likely that this is relevant, seeing as Service_A -> Service_C works just fine as well as calling Service_C from Service_B while the latter is run on localhost.

The problem occurred for the first time some time during the past week, and I am not aware of any changes to anything since then (though, obviously, *something* has changed *somewhere*).

So, I'm just wondering if anyone else has encountered this (to me at least) very strange issue, or have any tips for debugging.

(It *might* be related to the issue discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ca6372be-3169-4fb5-870f-bfbea605faf6/azure-webapp-webjob-exception-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), but I'm not sure, and it seems like it should have been resolved ages ago)

**UPDATE: This has resolved itself since the question was asked. I still have no idea what caused the issue, but it seems to have been a temporary issue with the web app instance in Azure.**

Comment: Try to provide a PCAP/Wireshark capture of the TLS handshake. Otherwise it's just guess work.

Comment: Thanks, but since this is only a problem in the Azure App Service container, that's not possible, as far as I can tell.

Comment: System.Net tracing should be enough to tell what's happening - see this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/05/enable-system-net-tracing-on-azure-app-service-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server/